# Should backend variables be updated to match frontend changes?

Tags: django, naming-conventions, conventions

A project I am working on involves categorising data into four separate categories. These categories are pivotal to the project logic and appear everywhere in the code. The project is pretty much finished.

Yesterday, the client asked us to rename the categories. This is a very simple change to appear in the frontend, only a few lines of code. However, the old names are used in many variable names spread throughout the backend, and it would take quite a while to comb through the code and update all variable names and comments.

Is it better to keep the old variable names and save time and keep things consistent for existing developers, or spend the time changing the variable names and ensure the frontend and backend are consistent and make things clearer for future development?

Comment: I think the answer here is that those 4 category names should not have been present in variable names in the first place but rather be defined as constants. This would allow a change of category names pretty easily in the backend. Now it's a bit of a trade-off. If the renaming would also include refactoring that would allow you to easily rename categories (or even add new ones) in the future then it's worth doing. Otherwise only making the changes in the frontend combined with proper documentation seems like a fair solution.

Comment: @GlennDJ they are present as constants (using a django choices model), which is why the frontend change is so easy. The variable issue is more for the variables related to those constants, e.g. "completes" as a variable holding all items where status is Status.COMPLETE  (the aforementioned static)